# Can Linux file permissions be fooled?

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions

I came across this example today and I wondered how reliable Linux file permissions are for hiding information

```
$ mkdir fooledYa
$ mkdir fooledYa/ohReally
$ chmod 0300 fooledYa/
$ cd fooledYa/
$ ls 
>>> ls: cannot open directory .: Permission denied
$ cd ohReally
$ ls -ld .
>>> drwxrwxr-x 2 user user 4096 2012-05-30 17:42 .
```

Now I am not a Linux OS expert, so I have no doubt that someone out there will explain to me that this is perfectly logical from the OS's point of view. However, my question still stands, is it possible to fool, not hack, the OS into letting you view files/inode info which you are not supposed to? What if I had issued the command `chmod 0000 fooledYa`, could an experienced programmer find some round about way to read a file such as `fooledYa/ohReally/foo.txt`?

Comment: so I think that `chmod 0300` would give `d-wx------` which would allow you to `cd` into the directory (due to `x`), but not list the files (no `r`). However because you didn't set the permissions recursively (`chmod -R 0300 fooledYa/`) the child directory `ohReally` has normal `drwx------` permissions, hence as you see.

Comment: @TomH That's how I rationalized it as well. At first glance, however, it appears that there are two permissions for the same inode info. One from `fooledYa` with read permissions revoked on all files/directories, and one from `ohReally` with read permissions granted on all files/directories INCLUDING `.` which points to itself.

Comment: I think the example would have to be more explicit, I don't see that as conflicting. Basically `chmod 0300 somedir` revokes the permission to read the `somedir` listing, and not anything to the contents.

Comment: I have used directory permissions like `0710` and `0711` for things that need to be visible to e.g. daemons but shouldn't be too easy for a casual user to get into. It isn't bullet-proof security, but for non-owner, non-root users, makes it just a little harder to look at the contents of the directory while still allowing access based on a full file path.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$ ls -lhd fooledYa/
d-wx------ #snip
```

First thing's first: I can write to the directory (make new entries) and I can execute (`cd`) to the directory. I can't read the directory, though. What that means isn't intuitive.

When you work with directories in Unix systems, the directory point to [inodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode), which are different things than the pointer entry. Being able to follow references down a directory tree is controlled by the `eXecute` bit. For each directory level down the tree, the operating system checks the execute bit before descending to the next level.

Meanwhile, the `Read` bit controls accessing the inode's contents. Everything you can reference on your filesystem is an inode entry. Directories or files, they point to an inode.

```
ls -ldi fooledYa/
121100226 d-wx------ #snip
```

In this case, the directory inode is 121100226. The read permission tells whether I can access that inode file in userspace to read its contents. The contents of the directory inode are the references to other files. The kernel can always read that. You as a user are controlled by the kernel's decisions regarding the entries within that.

Thus, since `ls` tries to read the contents to tell me what's there (as checked by the `Read` flag), it is denied. Since I still have `eXecute` permission, however, the kernel will allow me to traverse to files that I specify if the directories above the file I want all permit me to `eXecute` into them, regardless of whether I can read them to see what the reference.

So, to summarize for directories, think of execute as a master permission. Without it, you can't enter the directory to do anything. After that, think of them as a two column file. If you have read permission, you can see the entries. If you have write permission, you can add or remove entries. If you lack those two permissions but have execute, you can make references to entries in the list, but you cannot read the list.

This is a good illustrative examples of inodes and how they represent directory references and file block on disk references: http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2330/04f/notes/links_and_inodes.html

Answer (score 2):

As you anticipated, plenty of people have explained how your example is perfectly logical.  "Works as designed."

To answer your question, **it would be an egregious kernel bug if you were able to fool the OS into letting you view files/inode info which you are not supposed to.**  The file permissions are associated with the inode itself and are applied when you actually try to open the file. In case you didn't pick it up from the other answers, I'll point out that a directory has an inode like any file does, it's just that the permissions mean something slightly (or greatly) different when applied to directories.

File permissions are the original Unix security mechanism and are still an integral part of Unix/Linux security.  Any scenario you can cook up that looks like you have fooled the system is almost certainly a case of you not understanding what the correct behavior is. If you found a legitimate way to bypass security, even in hacks, it would be considered a critical security bug and would be among the highest priorities to patch.

For example, if you were able to read the contents of a file you were not supposed to be able to read, you could steal the (hashed) passwords of all the users and the private `ssh` key for the system and the private `ssh` keys of everyone on the system (though hopefully those would be encrypted) and via a device inode read the entire contents of system memory (and much more).  It would be less dangerous if you could read file info you were not supposed to, but it would still be considered a major breach.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the specific thing that is fooling you is that every directory below `/` has at least two links to it: the directory's entry in its parent and `.` within itself (plus any `..` links from child directories).  When you type `ls -ld .` it's looking at the `.` link in the current directory (which you have permission to read), not the link to the current directory from the parent directory (which you don't have permission to read).

For +x, I've found the easiest way to understand how it works on directories is permission to "get into" the directory.  You can't get into a directory without +x at all, even if you have read and write access to it. If you aren't allowed into a directory, you can't get into the subdirectories whether they have +x set or not. So, if you have `fooledYa/ohReally/foo.txt` and `fooledYa` is is chmod 0000, assuming no other ACL system overrides the file mode, only root would be able to get into `ohReally/` or open `foo.txt` even if they know the path to the file without having to list the directory contents.

One of the odd things about these permissions is that if the directory is +r but not +x, you have permissionto read the directory contents so you can "peek in" from outside and read the list of files in the directory, but without +x you won't be able to get into the directory to access (`stat`) the individual files.  Therefore if you try to `ls -l` such a directory you'll get filenames but all the other fields for filesizes, modes, ownership, etc will be `?` marks.